# How is this word order to be explained?

Tags: word-order

While discussing a story with 2 native German speakers I said:

> Und er ließ seine Augen mit Genugtuung über das reifende Feld gleiten, das mit den Blattreihen der Bohnen verziert waren, die **alle jetzt** im durchsichtigen Vorhang des Regens ummantelt waren.

and they corrected me as follows:

> Und er ließ seine Augen mit Genugtuung über das reifende Feld gleiten,
> das mit den Blattreihen der Bohnen verziert waren,
> die **jetzt alle** im durchsichtigen Vorhang des Regens ummantelt waren.

Why is the time adverbial more correctly placed between the subject and the direct object of the final clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Olafant said, the "corrected" version is more common and I had to read the "wrong" sentence a couple times to get it right.

The difference is as follows:

> die jetzt alle

Puts emphasis on *jetzt*. Here you basically say

> "Attention, it's happening **now** and to all of them"

While the other way around

> die alle jetzt

analogously puts attention on the fact, that it's all of them

> "Attention, it's **all** of them, and it's happening now

I suppose people usually emphasize the chronological importance, thus the first version is much more commonly heard/used and might cause the other (also correct) version to sound a bit off.

Comment: I thought about emphasis but couldn't really figure it out. If I read both of the sentences aloud, I would emphasize *alle* in both cases. But that's not mandatory. You have a point and one could see it this way. I think, the first version is more poetic.

Answer (score 2):

Both versions are fine.

> jetzt alle

might be more common. But there is nothing wrong with

> alle jetzt

But there is another error:

In

> ... über das reifende Feld gleiten, das mit den Blattreihen der Bohnen verziert waren ...

*waren* refers to *Feld*. Since *Feld* is singular,
it must be **war** instead of **waren**.

> ... das reifende Feld ..., das mit ... verziert war ...